# Algolia places.js complete form and link to a map

Tags: javascript, node.js, algolia

I'm trying to make autocomplete form with address which will be automatically set on a map.

Algolia let us do this but separatly with [complete form](https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#complete-form) and [link to map](https://community.algolia.com/places/examples.html#link-to-a-map).

What I'm looking for is to merge those algorithms. How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Places main event is the `change` event, which is leveraged in both of the examples you provided to update either the form or the map.

It seems that all that is needed is to combine the content of the `onChange` functions of the two examples. see this [image: jsFiddle] for example.

Comment: Thx it's exactly what I was looking for ! :D